# LINQ join multiple conditions

Tags: linq

I have formed the following LINQ query, but it gives error

> mcc_season is not an attribute in mcc_product

How do I form the query where I have 2 `WHERE` conditions and both from different entities in the join

```
var guestCardProduct =
           (from c in CrmOrgServiceContext.mcc_productpriceSet
            join d in CrmOrgServiceContext.mcc_productSet
            on c.mcc_product.Id equals d.mcc_productId
            where d.mcc_producttype.Value == (int)mcc_product.mcc_producttypeOptionSet.GuestCard
            && c.mcc_season.Id == seasonId
            select new
            {
                d.mcc_productId,
                c.mcc_price
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is here, because you haven't told us what you're really trying to do, or what your entities look like. That query should be fine if `mcc_season` really *is* a property of whatever type `c` is, but we don't know the types involved - and I'm inclined to trust the compiler. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Are you sure it does not say "mcc_season is not an attribute in mcc_productpriceSet"? Do you have foreign key mapping between mcc_season and mcc_productPriceSet?

Comment: As a side note, don't name your variables `c` and `d`.

Comment: I presume that you're programming in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to re-write it as follows:

```
var guestCardProduct = 
           (from c in CrmOrgServiceContext.mcc_productpriceSet 
            where c.mcc_season.Id == seasonId
            join d in CrmOrgServiceContext.mcc_productSet 
            on c.mcc_product.Id equals d.mcc_productId 
            where d.mcc_producttype.Value == (int)c.mcc_product.mcc_producttypeOptionSet.GuestCard 
            select new 
            { 
                d.mcc_productId, 
                c.mcc_price 
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

We're assuming here that there are 1 - 0..1 relationships between mcc_productpriceSet and both mcc_season and mcc_product and also a 1 - 0..1 relationship between mcc_product and mcc_producttypeOptionSet. If you have 1-n relationships between any of these, then you are going to have to work through those relationships rather than dotting into the single property because you will have collections of child objects rather than a single child object. You may find it helpful to break your query into smaller pieces to narrow down the source of the problem.